# Hebrew text in HTML files

Tags: html, character-encoding, hebrew

I just did a pretty major typesetting session putting things in order for a specific prayer in Hebrew named Tikkun Haklali. It's [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rfkrocktk/WxSP3/) on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net). Unfortunately, when I tried to save the HTML and CSS to my computer, I get something like this:

[image]

rather than something like this:

[image]

What gives? Character encoding? If so, what should I save my text file in?

Comment: how are you saving it? I suggest firefox, and save as "web page, complete", and make sure you're using UTF-8 (go to View > Character Encoding > Unicode (UTF-8))

Answer (score 32, accepted):

HTML Charset Encoding: UTF-8. That way the browser will render it correctly.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Place that right after `<head>`

Comment: Is there any reason not to do this on every HTML document?