# How to pass string in Hebrew

Tags: javascript, html

I made a register page in my site which sends to preview page before inserting the data to the database.

The problem is that it converts hebrew to gibberish (it works well with english). What can I do?
This is the function I use to pass the strings:

```
function getParams() {
  var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
  var params = new Array();
  if (idx != -1) {
    var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx + 1, document.URL.length).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
      nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
      params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
    }
  }
  return params;
}
```

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873290/hebrew-text-in-html-files

Comment: What do you mean by gibberish? Did you try applying [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to the query parameters after extracting them?

Comment: It doesn't help. 
I know there is something called hash code which is consists of numbers. Do you know how can I convert the string to hashcode and in the next page convert the hash code to string?