# Can't see hebrew letters in chrome in a self made html document

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm trying to build an html document and for some reason Hebrew letters are not shown correctly. Instead, all I see are these question marks �����.
I can see Hebrew letters in other websites. The html document is local, meaning I open it from my desktop.
Any ideas?
Thanks =)[image: Menu]

Comment: Where is your html code ?

Comment: I think that the question is duplicated [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873290/hebrew-text-in-html-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873290/hebrew-text-in-html-files)

Comment: Maybe the answer is... @Ronald

Answer (score 5):

Try the HTML Charset Encoding: UTF-8. That way the browser will render it correctly.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Place that right after `<head>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the browser that your content is `utf-8 encoded`. You can do that by adding **one** of the following `meta tags` to the `head` of your page:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Or

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

In `HTML5`, they are **equivalent**. Use the **shorter one**, it is easier to remember and type. Browser support is fine since it was designed for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was reckless... I am working with Notepad++ and wasn't aware that the default encoding is ANSI. I changed it to UTF-8 and now it works fine. Thank you for your aid.