# Google App Engine/Java - Hebrew arrives as question marks

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, google-app-engine, character-encoding

I am using Java/Spring and JSON. Saving Hebrew content is working well, I can see the text well on the data-store (stored as Text object).

From some reason I can not retrieve it well, all Hebrew characters turn to question marks.

Here is the server side code to demo the issue:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/SomeAction.html", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public String getQuestion(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response){
    String qKey = request.getParameter("key");
    Question q = new Question();
    q.setKey(qKey);
    Question question = QuestionUtils.getQuestionDetails(q);
    log.warn(question.getBody());
    return question.getBody()
}
```

In the logging I can see the hebrew very well. In the web-site I only see question marks.

Appreciate any help

Comment: all is rendered fine besides hebrew characters

Comment: I ended up base64 encoding the hebew text...

Comment: There is a similar situation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7873300/9015852 Try that in your html file.

Comment: solved it, I encoded the content via base64

Comment: Happy to hear that. Please post it as an answer so we all know you solved the issue.